# Django_tables2 data_list

Tags: python, django, django-tables2

I am new to django and django_tables2. I am trying to use django_tables2 in my apps view to create a table. I am trying to use this [link](https://django-tables2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pages/tables-for-models.html) as a tutorial.In my IndexView I have the following:

In my view.py

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    model = Post.objects.all()
    template_name = 'post/index.html'
    table = Post(data_list)
    RequestConfig(request).configure(table)
```

In my index.html:

```
{% load render_table from django_tables2 %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>Posts</h1>
    {% render_table post_list %}
{% endblock %}
```

I am getting the following error:

> name 'data_list' is not defined

How do I import and use data_list?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Your view can look something like this:

```
def IndexView(request):
    template_name = 'post/index.html'
    return render(request, template_name, {"post_list": Post.objects.all()})
```

Comment: I get the following error "'return' outside function" with that code.

Comment: Sorry my bad. I think in this case you should not use generic views as they do not add any benefit to you. So just make a regular view.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're trying to show all your Posts in the table.
So you've done:

model = Post.objects.all()

You then populate the table with the posts:

table = PostTable(model)

You are missing a table type, do you have a tables.py?

And data_list is undefined, it's a variable not some sort of defined type in django_tables2. You need to make data_list equal to something (e.g. models) because thats what it looks like you are trying to populate the table with.

Comment: the following has been changed table = PostTable(model) but I am getting a "name 'PostTable' is not defined" error

Comment: Have you made a tables.py and created a table for you post model in it?

Answer (score 0):

If PostTable is not defined, define it first say in your views.py, like the example below:

```
class ProjectTable(tables.Table): 
    title = tables.LinkColumn('project-detail',args=[A('pk')],verbose_name="Title")
    amount = tables.Column(verbose_name="Project Funds")
    start = tables.Column(verbose_name="Project Started")
    end = tables.Column(verbose_name="Project Ended")
    location = tables.Column(verbose_name="Project Location")
```

then fill that table with a queryset,

```
def list_projects(request):
    projects = Project.objects.all()
    etable = ProjectTable(projects)
    RequestConfig(request, paginate={"per_page": 7}).configure(etable)
    return render(request, "projectsapp/list.html", {'table':etable})
```

so like in the example data_list is equivalent to projects, meaning you must fill your PostTable with a queryset generated from FOO.objects.all()